# cordova-plugin-printer printing raw html instead of rendered html

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, printing, cordova-plugins

I am using [cordova-plugin-printer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-printer) for one of my [Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/) app. I have installed the plugin, and also able to access [android native printing service](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/printservice/PrintService). The plugin's print function can be called in app using it's function `cordova.plugins.printer.print();` as described in the plugin documents [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-printer) and on it's [git repository](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-printer).

I actually need to print a selected `<div>` from the HTML, using JavaScript/jQuery.

But the problem I'm facing is that when I am passing html as a `var` this plugin is printing raw HTML, and not the rendered HTML as desired. Where as, if I directly pass HTML code, as a parameter, it gives the desired result.

**My Example Code:**

When I call

`cordova.plugins.printer.print('<h1>How r u</h1>');//print as desired.`

But when I write code like this:

```
<div id="printable">
<h1>How are you</h1>
</div>

var printable = $("#printable").html();
cordova.plugins.printer.print(printable);//prints raw html
```

Can anyone help? or correct me what am I doing wrong? seems to be something silly, which I am probably unable to figure out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove line breaks from your html.
Try

```
 var printable = $("#printable").html();
 printable = printable.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, '');
 cordova.plugins.printer.print(printable);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Eric 

your solution worked, but it worked in combination with another solution, 
which I am mentioning below



```var printable = $("#printable").html();
printable = printable.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, '');//from stack 
printable = printable.replace(/>\s+</g,'><');
cordova.plugins.printer.print(printable);```